# warning : Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

Reusing code from a library example I got my paypal button working like a charm but now I have this warning comming from that component:

> Warning: Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated,
>   and will be removed in React v16.0. Use a plain JavaScript class
>   instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class v15.*
>   is available on npm as a temporary, drop-in replacement. For more info
>   see printWarning @
>   lowPriorityWarning.js:38 lowPriorityWarning @ lowPriorityWarning.js:57
>   get @ React.js:106 register @ checkout.lib.js:7165 Component.driver @
>   checkout.lib.js:5247 ./src/components/presentational/PayPalButton.js @
>   PayPalButton.js:6
>   **webpack_require**

so since the problem is comming from line 6 it might be the way Button is created:

```
const Button = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM })
```

I tried [this link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.createclass) provided in the warning but didn't help much and I don't know how to import it or create it differently, this is my complete code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import paypal from 'paypal-checkout'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Button = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM })

export default class PayPalButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      env: this.props.env,

      client: {
        sandbox: this.props.sandboxID,
        production: this.props.productionID
      },
      amount: this.props.amount,
      currency: this.props.currency,
      commit: this.props.commit
    }
  }

  payment(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
      transactions: [
        {
          amount: { total: this.state.amount, currency: this.state.currency }
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  onAuthorize(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute().then((payment_data)=>{
      var payment = {}
      payment.paid = true
      payment.cancelled = false
      payment.payerID = data.payerID
      payment.paymentID = data.paymentID
      payment.paymentToken = data.paymentToken
      payment.returnUrl = data.returnUrl
      // getting buyer's shipping address and email
      payment.address = payment_data.payer.payer_info.shipping_address
      payment.email = payment_data.payer.payer_info.email
      this.props.paymentDone(payment)

    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log ('error PayPal'+err)
        throw err
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        commit={ this.state.commit }

        env={ this.state.env }
        client={ this.state.client }

        payment={ (data, actions) => this.payment(data, actions) }
        onAuthorize={ (data, actions) => this.onAuthorize(data, actions) }
        onCancel={this.props.onCancel}
        onError = {this.props.onError}
      />
    )
  }
}

PayPalButton.propTypes = {
  env: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  sandboxID: PropTypes.string,
  productionID: PropTypes.string,
  amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  currency: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  commit: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Are you using React 16? If not, you do not have to do anything except maybe file a GitHub issue for the component's creator to update it. This isn't an issue with your code, but the library that you're using.

Comment: Hi Matt , you are right, I'm using "react": "^15.6.2", so It would be alright,
I did open an issue on the repo too, I was trying to solve it from my end wrapping the object somehow, but I can't find a way so, I guess I'll just leave it to them.